# Opening GeoTIFF (georeferenced in ArcGIS for Desktop) in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, raster, geotiff-tiff, georeferencing

I tried to open a georeferenced geotiff created in ArcGIS for Desktop in QGIS.

I could open them, but they are not in the right spot.

These raster datasets contains .aux .rrd .tfwx  .tif.aux.xml  .tif.xml and .tif files.
I can open them in ArcMap without problem.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, AndreJ. But I couldn't open images correctly..

Comment: I checked some similar Q and A, and I removed the x from the tfwx files. Then I could open them in QGIS.

Answer (score 2):

Under `Settings -> Options`, `CRS` tab, enable `Prompt for CRS` for new layers.

Then you will be asked explicitely for the CRS, which should be the same as you georeferenced to in Arcgis.

You might get a datum shift of up to 100m, as this is not stored by Arcgis. But QGIS has bundled the shift with the common projection definitions.

Answer (score 0):

With the georeferencing toolbar click rectify create a new tif.import that into QGIS